# Center image in GitHub's README.org

Tags: org-mode, html, github, markup

I want to center an image in my project's GitHub README.org file, but everything I've tried so far hasn't worked:

```
#+ATTR_HTML style="center"
[[/path/to/img.png]]


#+ATTR_HTML align="center"
[[/path/to/img.png]]

#+begin_center
[[/path/to/img.png]]
#+end_center
```

Is this possible, or should I just go the low-friction route and use Markdown?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can embed "raw" html as follows:

```
<p align="center"><img src="images/wim-128.png" /></p>
```

When displayed on GitHub.com, for some reason org-mode's image styling directives are ignored.

However GitHub does not ignore styling of `<p>` tags, so I used the above fix.

Comment: note: it worked with `#+html:`. thanks.

Comment: Just to give a complete example, to center an image in a README.org on GitHub, one would write 
`#+html: <p align="center"><img src="images/wim-128.png" /></p>`.

Answer (score 5):

To center with CSS, you need to use `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;`

try this

```
#+ATTR_HTML: :style margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
[[/path/to/img.png]]
```

Comment: When I did this I end up with the text `#+ATTR_HTML ...` visible in the rendered [README](https://github.com/hoosierEE/wim/blob/1e3f0d5667eeb13d6fd20eeea95df4a1f8c705d6/README.org).

Comment: @hoosierEE i modified the answer so the solution should be correct. I tried it and it works.

Comment: I guess either GitHub's version of [org-ruby](https://github.com/bdewey/org-ruby), or their own CSS, removes these styles before rendering on github.com.  Thanks for trying though, and by the way I really like your ErgoEmacs site!

Comment: @hoosierEE thanks, and glad you found the answer. I forgot about the github layer.